# Eclipse EGit Rebase w/merge

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, egit

I and a friend of mine started to use git recently and now work on a project.
Now I messed something up with pulling and fetching and now I am stuck in something (is it a branch?!).
Normally Ecipse shows [master] next to my project in the project explorer, and I can push and pull to/from master branch. Because something went wrong, I got a merge conflict. Since I do not understand a single internet tutorial for solving merge conflicts (they all told me to use the merge tool. What to do with this magic tool, they do not state... well good tutorial, I assume. There are some buttons in the tool, but some does not have any effect, some does not work always and even if both sides of the files in conflict show exactly the same, the conflict does not get marked as solved and I can't find any way to mark it solved manually. Thanks)
So I want to overwrite everything to its original state and to do so, I tried to switch back to "master"-branch.
... It does not let me. 
So please, tell me, how can I solve those god damn conflicts, how can I add folders to .gitignore (I added a folder called "jars" but some files of the folder still gets pushed) and HOW CAN I ESCAPE THIS REBASE?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can just `abort` rebase. Using console it would be `git rebase --abort`

Comment: In `Repositories` view find option `Rebase` and then use `Abort`

Answer (score 0):

you can also go to `Git Staging` view in Eclipse and click on `Abort` button